# Failed to start glassfish service with error code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have installed glassfish 5 successfully and even managed to create a new domain and deploy my application successfully but whenever I stop and try to start the glassfish service again it fails to start completely. I have browsed all over the internet and non of the solutions have worked. Here is my journal -xe logs for the error. Hope someone can point out what I might have done wrong during the installation process `enter code here`

Comment: Hi - are you aware of the successor of Glassfish, called Payara? This application server builds forth on Glassifish, but Payara has a live community. Maybe, there is help there - in the Payara-forum.

Comment: I have not checked it out...perhaps later...kindly help with my situation at the moment

Comment: How are you starting and stopping Glassfish? From the command prompt, or within an IDE such as Intellij IDEA, Eclipse or NetBeans? Also, one thing you could try is to [download and try using Glassfish 5.0.1](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/nightly). It's not formally released yet, so don't use it in a Production environment, but it might solve your problem. Also, you need to fix your post so we can view your log.

Comment: I am using command prompt with this command systemctl start glassfish.service

Comment: @MbaiMburu Please update your post so we can see your log. Either paste the relevant portion, or provide a working link to it. It's not really possible to resolve your problem without more information.

Comment: I managed to resolve the problem thanks. The JDK directory had wrong permissions, it worked after changing permissions making it accessing to all users.